# What is the relation between bases of a vector subspace and bases of its vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have two vector spaces $V$, $W$. $V$ is four-dimensional and $W$ is six-dimensional. Suppose that $U$ is a two-dimensional vector subspace of $V$. What is the relation between bases of $U$ and bases of $V$?

Answer (score 0):

Not much, other than that every basis of $U$ can be extended to a basis of $V$.

In particular it is not true that every basis of $V$ contains a basis of $U$ as a subset.

Incidentally I'm not sure where $W$ comes in to your question.